# Searching lucene Index more than once returns zero result

Tags: java, lucene

Well, I am trying to start with lucene and I am using this example [here](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/sample-apps/textfileindexer-java.html) which is a console example. I run it through eclipse but everything seems to work smoothly until I conduct a second search.

The program briefly does the following:

1. Uses an `IndexWriter` and populates it with `Document`s.
2. Creates a `IndexReader`: `IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexLocation)));`
3. Creates an `IndexSearcher`: `IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);`
4. Creates a `TopScoreDocCollector`: `TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5, true);`

I am mentioning these because I am not familiar with lucene and I am trying to narrow down the problem.

Then there is a loop where a query (`String`) is read by the console and the following commands are executed:

```
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, "contents", analyzer).parse(s);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

Everything works smoothly as I mentioned before in the first loop. After that there is no result returned (`hits` is empty).

My question is whether I should reset/clean the searcher or something.
`Query q` seems to acquire the correct query in the next times also so I don't think the problem to be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, reusing the `Collector` in that way was causing issues.  The explanation is simply that `Collector` is stateful, and not designed for reuse.

Really there is no need to use `Collector` here at all.  It's considered an 'Expert' API, and is entirely unnecessary here.  It's a bit puzzling that the author of that example used it.  Just change:

```
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "contents", analyzer).parse(s);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

To:

```
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "contents", analyzer).parse(s);
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, 5);
ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;
```

Also, doesn't look like the `IndexReader` is ever closed there.  Might be a good idea to add that.

Comment: Thanks I will add your modification and close the `IndexReader`. As for the the `collector` when it is meant to be used anyway? Can you give any example or link?

Comment: Sure, Check out [IndexSearcher itself](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.0.0/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.java#IndexSearcher.search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Weight%2Corg.apache.lucene.search.Filter%2Cint%2Corg.apache.lucene.search.Sort%2Cboolean%29).  Under the covers, it uses a collector to collect hits using the method I've recommended.  It can be used if you need to have more control over the process, I suppose, but if you just need to run a search and get results, it's generally not necessary to use it directly.

Comment: You can streamline performance in certain cases, or exert control over scoring, sorting, or which results are returned in ways not provided directly otherwise.  A few examples of collectors that may depart from the standard way hits are collected, as examples:  TotalHitCountCollector, CachingCollector, TimeLimitingCollector, PositiveScoresOnlyCollector, and EarlyTerminatingSortingCollector

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error research I find out that the I had to create a new `Collector` for each query to work.

I just added `collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5, true);` inside the loop and it worked.

I don't know why though. If someone has an explanation for this it is welcome to share it.